# Memory/Handle/Gdi leak utility

Tags: memory, gdi, utilities, handles

I remember from past having a utility that would allow to leak various system resources, such as memory, handles and gdi. It had a small dialog where one would choose what to leak, it was nice for system stress testing.. I don't remember whether it was part of VC6 or I got it from somewhere else.

If you know such tool, please let me know it's name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of two things that fit your description. Both were published in MSDN Mag a few years ago.

[GDI Leaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188782.aspx)

[Leaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301756.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but actually what I needed was a tool that will leak desktop heap memory and I found one at sysinternals(not in suite), hope it will help some one else http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/Testlimit.zip

Answer (score 3):

How long ago was it? I'm not sure, but I think you've used something similar to Deleaker. Have a look at their website: http://deleaker.com/